# Mongoose aggregate query $max in $match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to mongoose, I am facing a problem while trying to fetch some data using aggregate query.

One part of my auction schema is:

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("56c58be1faaa402c0d4ae66f"),
        "auction_name" : "Auction2",
        "auction_start_datetime" : ISODate("2016-02-18T09:30:00.000Z"),
        "auction_end_datetime" : ISODate("2016-02-22T09:00:00.000Z"),
        "auction_status" : "active",
        "auction_series" : "GA-06-C",
        "auction_reserve_price" : 1000,
        "auction_increment_amount" : 200,
        "fancy_numbers" : [ 
            {
                "number_end_datetime" : ISODate("2016-02-22T09:00:00.000Z"),
                "number_start_datetime" : ISODate("2016-02-18T09:30:00.000Z"),
                "increment_amount" : 200,
                "reserve_price" : 1000,
                "number" : 5000,
                "_id" : ObjectId("56c58da3faaa402c0d4ae739"),
                "bid_users" : [ 
                    {
                        "user_id" : "56c416a599ad7c9c1611b90b",
                        "bid_amount" : 7200,
                        "bid_time" : ISODate("2016-02-18T11:58:53.025Z"),
                        "user_name" : "amit@mailinator.com",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5aec4acebf3b4061a645e")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "user_id" : "56c172dc302a2c90179c7fd1",
                        "bid_amount" : 15400,
                        "bid_time" : ISODate("2016-02-19T10:38:43.506Z"),
                        "user_name" : "rbidder@mailinator.com",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5afe0d2baef7020ede1b6")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "user_id" : "56c477afb27a7ed824c54427",
                        "bid_amount" : 2800,
                        "bid_time" : ISODate("2016-02-18T11:56:58.830Z"),
                        "user_name" : "bidder2@mailinator.com",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5b18a78c3fb340a8c6d75")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "user_id" : "56c5b17378c3fb340a8c6d73",
                        "bid_amount" : 5600,
                        "bid_time" : ISODate("2016-02-18T11:58:34.616Z"),
                        "user_name" : "bidder3@mailinator.com",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5b1d778c3fb340a8c6d78")
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

Here, fancy_number is an array under auction collection and bid_users is an array under each fancy_number.

I have the user_id, I want to query and get only the bid_user records in which he is the highest bidder.

For example:

> There are 3 users bidded 200,300,400 respectively, I want to get the
>   record (i.e number and amount) only if this particular user bid is 400
>   (highest). where ill be passing the user_id

The aggregate query which I wrote is:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
tempId = new ObjectID(req.body.aId);

auctionModel.aggregate({$match: {'_id': tempId}},
                        {$unwind: '$fancy_numbers'},
                        {$unwind:"$fancy_numbers.bid_users"},
                        {$group: {'_id':"$fancy_numbers.number" , maxBid: { $max: '$fancy_numbers.bid_users.bid_amount'}}},  
    function(err, bidData){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error :' + err);
        }
        else if(bidData) {
            console.log(bidData);
        }
     });
```

Somehow this query is not working, its only giving records of max bid and number. I want records only if he is the highest bidder.

Comment: Please can anyone look into this.

Answer (score 1):

If I catch you correctly, please try to do it through `$sort`, and `$limit` to retrieve the highest bidder as below

```
auctionModel.aggregate(.aggregate([
                            {$match: {'_id': '123'}}, 
                            {$unwind: '$fancy_numbers'}, 
                            {$unwind: '$fancy_numbers.bid_users'}, 
                            {$sort: {bid_amount: 1}}, 
                            {$limit: 1}]);
```